# reset filter on tablesorter when going back to page and filtered select drop-down returns no records

Tags: tablesorter

I am using tablesorter on a page where I display products. One of the column is the status displayed in a drop-down. When I click a product I can edit it and change its status. When I go back to the product list, the list is still filtered which is OK but if the product was the last with this status, the product list is, of course, empty and the drop-down shows no selection because the status does not exist anymore. I want to clear the filter on the drop-down when I get back on the product list page and there is no more product with this status. How can I achieve this?

My code:

```
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" id="ProductTable" class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="reorder-false reorder-block-left">Product Name</th>
            <th class="">Description</th>
            <th class="filter-select filter-onlyAvail">Status</th>
            <th class="">Status Change Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="ProductList">
    <tr class="ProductRows" id="P_1906">
        <td ><a style="text-decoration:none" href="/Product/Index/1906">Product #1</a></td>
        <td><span class="">Test #1</span></td>
        <td><span class="">Active</span></td>
        <td><span class="time">2015/07/13 16:41:03</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="ProductRows" id="P_1993">
        <td ><a style="text-decoration:none" href="/Product/Index/1993">Test #2</a></td>
        <td><span class="">Test #2</span></td>
        <td><span class="">Backorder</span></td>
        <td><span class="time">2015/08/25 10:39:23</span></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

$("#ProductTable").tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    widthFixed: false,
    widgets: [ "zebra", "filter", "resizable" ],
    widgetOptions: {
        filter_childRows: false,
        filter_columnFilters: true,
        filter_filteredRow: 'filtered',
        filter_hideFilters: true,
        filter_ignoreCase: true,
        filter_liveSearch: true,
        filter_onlyAvail: 'filter-onlyAvail',
        filter_reset: 'button.reset',
        filter_saveFilters: true,
        filter_searchDelay: 300,
        filter_serversideFiltering: false,
        filter_startsWith: false,
        filter_useParsedData: false,
        filter_defaultAttrib: 'data-value'
    }
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show the code where you edit the status? When the cache gets updated, you can clear the filter before calling the update.

Comment: The status gets updated in a different page. Then when I return to the product list page, the table list seems empty because of the filter and the newly edited product has a different status.

Comment: Is the tablesorter "updateCell" or "update" method used? I'd still like to see some of that code.

Comment: No "updateCell" or "update" method used. The table is built dynamically in C# and not in JS. So let's say I have 2 records to display, the first has status "Active" and the second is "Backorder". The filter selection on Status is a drop-down, so I select "Active" to view the only active record. Then I click on the record to bring me to edit this record where I change the status to "Backorder". When I go back to the page, even though the status filter seems to be empty, Then it shows only "Backorder" but since there is now 0 Backorder items, the list is empty.

Comment: I have to click the select box and force to remove the filter to view all records again. I want to clear the filter automatically when the drop-down filters for something but list comes empty. There must be something around looping through table rows and check if all rows are filtered out. Then if it's the case clear filter.

Comment: Oh, then set the `filter_saveFilters` option to `false` otherwise it uses local storage to "remember" the last search.

Comment: I really need `filter_saveFilters` option set to `true`. I want to "remember" the last search. See my solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it using the following code:

```
var FilterCallOnce = false;

    $("#ProductTable").tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        widthFixed: false,
        widgets: [ "zebra", "filter", "resizable" ],
        widgetOptions: {
            filter_childRows: false,
            filter_columnFilters: true,
            filter_filteredRow: 'filtered',
            filter_hideFilters: true,
            filter_ignoreCase: true,
            filter_liveSearch: true,
            filter_onlyAvail: 'filter-onlyAvail',
            filter_reset: 'button.reset',
            filter_saveFilters: true,
            filter_searchDelay: 300,
            filter_serversideFiltering: false,
            filter_startsWith: false,
            filter_useParsedData: false,
            filter_defaultAttrib: 'data-value'
        }
    }).bind('filterEnd', function(e, filter){
        var table = document.getElementById("ProductList");
        var nrow = 0;
        var nfiltered = 0;

        if (FilterCallOnce == false)
        {
            FilterCallOnce = true;

            if (table != null)
            {
                for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++)
                {
                    nrow++;

                    if (!hasClass(row, 'filtered'))
                        nfiltered++;
                }

                if ((nrow > 0) && (nfiltered == 0))
                    $('#ProductTable').trigger('filterReset');
            }
        }
    });

    function hasClass(element, cls)
    {
        return (' ' + element.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cls + ' ') > -1;
    }
```